# Error in Python script, when trying to save Credentials after login with OAuth2 to Youtube Account

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

I have some error in this code, but cannt figure out where.

```
import os
import pickle
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = None

# token.pickle stores the user's credentials from previously successful logins
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    print('Loading Credentials From File...')
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        credentials = pickle.load(token)

# If there are no valid credentials available, then either refresh the token or log in.
if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
    if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
        print('Refreshing Access Token...')
        credentials.refresh(Request())
    else:
        print('Fetching New Tokens...')
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'client_secrets.json',
            scopes=[
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
            ]
        )

        flow.run_local_server(host='localhost', port=8080, prompt='consent',
                              authorization_prompt_message='')
        credentials = flow.credentials

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            print('Saving Credentials for Future Use...')
            pickle.dump(credentials, f)
```

After successfull login to YouTube Account using OAuth2 in Web Browser it gives me this Traceback in Sublime text:

```
Fetching New Tokens...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\youtube API\OAuthTest.py", line 29, in <module>
    flow.run_local_server(host='localhost', port=8080, prompt='consent',
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 511, in run_local_server
    self.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 298, in fetch_token
    kwargs.setdefault("client_secret", self.client_config["client_secret"])
KeyError: 'client_secret'
[Finished in 9.9s]
```

Also in Sublime Editor near line `flow.run_local_server(host='localhost', port=8080, prompt='consent', authorization_prompt_message='')` it gives red pop up `File (name of this script), line (this line), in <module>`

I am trying to create script for login and save my Credentials for further use without login again. Need this to use Youtube API for managing my channel.

I am beginner and used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQQEaSnQ_bs) as guide, but for me gives described issue. Also, I have client_secrets.json file (contain my OAuth 2.0 Client ID) saved in same folder, where my Python script is. In Google Console added Authorized redirect URIs `http://localhost:8080/` in my Web application, used for OAuth login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer myself, after some digging into code I have found that Google Console not save Your Client Secret in `*.json` file, if you downloading it 2nd time (not immidiately after creating OAuth), so this was issue (I make edits in URl's and got json without `client_secret`), after remaking OAuth and downloading normal `*.json` file (with `client_secret`), seems all works as should.